# Hamburger icon not showing on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar on my Django application. The code for it is below.

```css
.nav-header {
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #2e2e2e;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.brand-logo {
    max-width: 75px;
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 0px;
}

.brand-logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.navigation {
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
}

.navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.navigation li a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 28px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li a i {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.show-menu-btn,
.hide-menu-btn {
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
}

.show-menu-btn {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: right;
}

.show-menu-btn i {
    line-height: 100px;
}

.navigation a:hover,
.show-menu-btn:hover,
.hide-menu-btn:hover {
    color: #00ff0a;
}

#toggle-btn {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -1111;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .show-menu-btn,
    .hide-menu-btn {
        display: block;
    }

    .navigation {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #2e2e2e;
        top: -100%;
        left: 0;
        padding: 50px 0px;
        transition: 1s;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .navigation li {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navigation li a {
        padding: 15px 15px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .navigation li a i {
        width: auto;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .hide-menu-btn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 20px;
    }

    #toggle-btn:checked ~ nav .navigation {
        top: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-btn">
    <label for="toggle-btn" class="show-menu-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>

    <nav>
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}"><i class="fas fa-house-damage"></i> Home</a></li>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'signout' %}"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Sign Out</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'signin' %}"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Sign In</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'signup' %}"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <label for="toggle-btn" class="hide-menu-btn"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

When I test it locally in google chrome on my PC using the device toolbar, it works completely fine. When I deploy it to my Heroku server, the hamburger icon does not show.
The label is there it just is not visible. When I try to randomly tap the screen in the area where it is supposed to be, it works but still does not show.

Comment: Do you have a link to the front-end by chance? Doesn't seem to be coming through I would assume because of your Python Django. The mobile view seems to come in though.

Comment: The app is deployed here https://radiant-wildwood-82518.herokuapp.com

Comment: On mobile it works on opera mini but not on chrome.